# How to mount an Android sdcardfs formatted microSD card in Linux?

Tags: cyanogenmod, external-sd, sd-card, file-system, mount

Suppose I take out the microSD card from my Cyanogenmod 13/Android 6 phone, put it in a card reader and want to access it within my Ubuntu desktop. The first partition (16M) mounts automatically, guess its FAT32 but as soon as I want to mount the second partition (64G) it tells me that the filesystem is unknown.

Now I learned that my microSD card is likely to be formatted with sdcardfs, so I wonder how to get access within Ubuntu?

Comment: If you had formatted the sdcard as internal storage in marshmallow, then you cannot use that sdcard in any other device since it gets encrypted.

Comment: SDCards are not formatted as sdcardfs. sdcardfs is a FUSE-like filesystem to emulate `/data/media` on `/sdcard`. Android's supported filesystems must not be "unknown" to Linux distros. If it's so, the partition must be encrypted as @kp91 mentioned.